# Solving $\frac{\cos^23t}{\tan t}+\frac{\cos^2t}{\tan3t}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, problem-solving

I am having trouble solving the trigonometric equation below:
$$\frac{\cos^2\left(3t\right)}{\tan\left(t\right)}+\frac{\cos^2\left(t\right)}{\tan\left(3t\right)}=0$$

I would appreciate any help you can give me!
Thank you!

Comment: We would  appreciate  showing what you  did !

Comment: Please clarify what kind of trouble you are having. What methods do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: Generally with these things, decide which side of the equation looks messiest, then convert $\sec,\tan,\cot,\csc$ functions to $\cos,\sin$ functions.  Apply any double angle identities, until everything is in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ and simplify.

Comment: Since answerers have as yet only tackled the first problem, and since you have now asked about your own solution to the third problem in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3947660/409), you should take the opportunity to edit this question down. Specifically: remove the second and third problems, and ask the second one separately. (A question should include only one problem.)

Comment: that is a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

I will do the first one, hopefully, it will give you some ideas how to tackle the rest.

$\frac {\cos^2 3t}{\tan t} + \frac {\cos^2 t}{\tan 3t} = 0$

Find the common denominator and make this into one fraction.

$\frac {\cos^2 3t\tan 3t + \cos^2t\tan t}{\tan 3t\tan t} = 0$

Lets focus on the numerator.  If this expression equals $0$ then the numerator equals $0$ and the denominator does not equal $0.$

$\cos^2 3t\tan 3t + \cos^2t\tan t = 0$

use: $\tan t = \frac {\sin t}{\cos t}$ and cancel.

$\cos 3t\sin 3t + \cos t\tan t = 0$

I want to use $2\cos t\sin t = \sin 2t$

$2\cos 3t\sin 3t + 2\cos t\tan t = 0\\
\sin 6t + \cos t\tan t = 0$

The next step is a little bit obscure... $\sin 3t = (4\sin t - 3\sin^3 t)$

$3\sin 2t - 4\sin^3 2t + \sin 2t = 0$

Everything is in terms of $\sin 2t$!

$u=\sin 2t$ will make what we have look more like a polynomial.

$4u - 4u^3 = 0\\
u(1-u)(1+u)= 0\\
u = 0, \pm 1$

Reverse the substitution.

$\sin 2t = 0 \text { or } \pm 1$

$t = 0, \pm\frac {\pi}{2}, \pm \frac {\pi}{4}, \pm \frac{3\pi}{4}+ n\pi$

But if $t=0$ the denominator in the original expression equals 0, and we are going to throw that answer away.  And $\tan t$ is not defined at $t = \pm\frac {\pi}{2}$ so we should disregard that solution, too.

$t = \frac {(2n+1)\pi}{4}$

Comment: Isn't it easier to go with $\cos3t\sin3t+\cos t\sin t=0$, hence $\sin6t=\sin(-2t)$?

Comment: I suppose it is, frankly, that hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a slightly different approach from @Doug M. One has that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos^{2}(3t)}{\tan(t)} + \frac{\cos^{2}(t)}{\tan(3t)} = 0 & \Rightarrow \cos^{2}(3t)\tan(3t) + \cos^{2}(t)\tan(t) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \cos(3t)\sin(3t) + \cos(t)\sin(t) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \sin(6t) + \sin(2t) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \sin(6t) = \sin(-2t)
\end{align*}

After solving such equation, verify whether the solutions satisfy $\tan(t)\tan(3t)\neq 0$.

Can you take it from here?