# Solving $(\sin x-\cos x)^2+\tan x=2\sin^2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, problem-solving

From this post ([Solving $\frac{\cos^23t}{\tan t}+\frac{\cos^2t}{\tan3t}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3947542)), which is my post, I have tried solving the last equation. I have gotten a solution(s). Would like to see if I did correctly.

$$\bigl(\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(x\right)\bigr)^2+\tan\left(x\right)=2\sin^2\left(x\right)$$

Expanding:
$$sin^2\left(x\right)-2sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)+\cos^2\left(x\right)+tan\left(x\right)=2\sin^2\left(x\right)$$
Using $\sin^2\left(x\right)+\cos^2\left(x\right)=1$, and bringing the RHS to the LHS, the expansion becomes:
$$-2sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)-2\sin^2\left(x\right)+1+\tan\left(x\right)=0$$
Then using $\tan\left(x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}$ and multiplying the LHS by cos(x), I get the following:
$$\frac{-2\sin\left(x\right)\cos^2\left(x\right)-2\sin^2\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}=0$$

Now strictly dealing with the numerator, making two separate terms, one being $-2\sin\left(x\right)\cos^2\left(x\right)-2\sin^2\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)$ and the other being $\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)$, then factoring out $-2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, I get

$$\color{blue}{-2\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)+1}\color{red}{\bigl(\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)\bigr)}+\color{red}{\bigl(\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)\bigr)}=0$$

This makes two terms
$$\biggl(\color{blue}{-2\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)+1}\biggr)\biggl(\color{red}{\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)}\biggr)=0$$

For the first term, aka the red term, I got $$\tan(x)=-1$$
where $$x=\frac{3\pi}{4}+n\pi $$

and the second term, aka the blue term.
using the identity $\sin\left(2x\right)=2\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)$
$$\sin(2x)=1$$
where $$x=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$$

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It sounds good. Well done!

Comment: Did you check your answers by seeing whether they work in the original equation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson They satisfy the original equation because

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi n}{2}\right) \neq 0$$

Comment: @APC, good – I was suggesting that OP get in the habit of checking to see that no extraneous roots had crept in.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is a good advice indeed.

Comment: I will check to see next time and the time after that and the time after that....every time!! lol

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

\begin{align}
& (\sin x-\cos x)^2+\tan x-2\sin^2x\\
=& (1-\sin2x )+\tan x -(1-\cos 2x) \\
=&- \frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2 x}+ \tan x+\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2 x}\\
= &\frac1{1+\tan^2x}(\tan x-1)^2(\tan x+1)=0
\end{align}
Thus, $\tan x= \pm1$, leading to the solutions
$$x =\frac\pi4 +\frac{\pi n}2$$